# Laravel Eloquent Join multi tables

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I am has some problem with my eloquent joins.
I have 4 tables relation

**Loan Table** / Loans

```
 loan_id | quantity | user_id
 1       |   4      |   1   .
```

**Detail Loan Table** /Loandetails

```
 loandetail_id | loan_id | inventory_id
 1             | 1       | 4          .
```

**Inventory Table** /Inventories

```
inventory_id  | name_inventory
  4           | Keyboard     .
```

**User Table** /Users

```
user_id  | Name
  1      | This is my name
```

I want the result like this with eloquent queries

```
{
   'loan_id' => 1,
   'inventory' => 'keyboard',
   'user' => 'This is my name',
   'quantity' => 4
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have the following relationships mapped in your models.

**Loan.php**

```
public function loanDetails()
{
    return $this->hasMany(LoanDetail::class);
}

public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
```

**LoanDetails.php**

```
public function inventory()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Inventory::class);
}

public function loan()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Loan::class);
}
```

Arter that you can do it like this to query the data from the database,

```
$loan = Loan::with('loanDetails.user', 'loanDetails.inventory')->find(1);
```

then to get the result you want like this,

```
return [
            'loan_id' => $loan->id,
            'inventory' => $loan->inventory, //this will return the full inventory object you can do  $loan->inventory->name_inventory to access attributes
            'user' => $loan->user->name,
            'quantity' => $loan->quantity 
        ]
```

Comment: this is error response `Call to undefined relationship [Loandetails] on model [App\Loan].` 
thisis my model https://pastebin.com/AGRPRkmm

Comment: I assumed wrong you haven't mapped all relationships, let me update the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = DB::table('loan')
        ->select('loan.id as loan_id','invetoris.name_inventory as inventory','users.Name as users', 'loan.quantity' )
        ->join('loandetail', 'loandetail.loan_id', '=', 'loan.loan_id')
        ->join('inventoris', 'inventoris.inventory_id', '=', 'loandetail.inventory_id')->join('users', 'users.user_id', '=', 'loan.user_id')
        ->get()->toArray();



$info = [];
foreach($data as $key => $val) {
$info[] = [
'loan_id' => $val['loan_id'],
'inventory' => $val['inventory'],
'user' => $val['users'],
'quantity' => $val['quantity']
]; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $data = DB::table('Loan')
    ->select('Loan.id as loan_id','Inventories.name_inventory as 
             inventory','Users.Name as users', 'Loan.quantity' )
    ->join('Loandetails', 'Loandetails.loan_id', '=', 'Loan.loan_id')
    ->join('Inventories', 'Inventories.inventory_id', '=', 
           'Loandetails.inventory_id')
    ->join('Users', 'Users.user_id', '=', 'Loan.user_id')
    ->get()->toArray();
```